# Apostrophe s question

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Do I need to add an apostrophe 's' to parents (parents') in the sentence below:

Which is correct:

Option A:
This study seeks to compile recommendations for hearing parents parenting children with a hearing impediment.

Option B:
This study seeks to compile recommendations for hearing parents' parenting children with a hearing impediment.

Comment: Both: with Option A, the recommendations are for the parents, and with Option B for the parentING; both make sense.

Comment: *Parents parenting* is awkward, so no apostrophe gonna fix that. Maybe *parents raising*. Maybe *parents raising a child with a hearing impairment*. Typically, the study will not say what it will *do*, only what it will *seek* to do.

Comment: I confess the form *parenting* has always struck me as a bit barbarous, since the *-ent-* and *-ing* bits are both on the same grammatical job of turning something else into a present participle.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful responses. I realize it sounds awkward, but it must be 'parents parenting' as this is the focus of the paper.

Comment: **1.** […] *parenting children* is a reduced relative clause: =  […] for hearing parents *[who are]* parenting children with a hearing impediment.  **2.** […] for(prep.) {hearing(adj.) parents(n. and subject) *[who(rel.pron.) are(v.)]* parenting (pres. part.) {children(n.) with a hearing impediment.}} = preposition(for) + Noun Phrase = modifier modifying “recommendations”.

Answer (score 3):

No apostrophe is necessary since "parenting" here is acting  as a normal verb and not a gerund. As it is acting as a verb it is something the parents are doing, not something they 'own' in any sense.

If you said "The study provides recommendations for parents' parenting *of* children with a hearing impairment" the apostrophe would be needed as "parenting" would then be acting as a noun and the parenting would be a concept or action which was 'owned by' the parents rather than an action they were performing.